# jQuery Accordion populated by XML file, how?

Tags: jquery, xml, accordion, feed

I'm pulling my hair out here!  Is there a tutorial or snippets to enable me to create an accordion that is powered/populated by an XML file?

Currently my XML file is loaded ok, but every entry appears in a single accordion header.. obviously I need each XML chunk in a different accordion thingy..

My head hurts!

update:

```
<forces>
  <force>
    <region>ACPO London Region></region>
    <name>City of London Police</name>
    <url>cityoflondon.police.uk</url>
    <address>37 Wood Street London EC2P 2NQ</address>
    <phone>020 7601 2455</phone>
    <logo>logo_city.gif</logo>
  </force> 
... 
<forces>
```

Comment: what is the format of you xml (show a snippet)

Comment: <forces>
    <force>
      <region>ACPO London Region></region>
      <name>City of London Police</name>
      <url>http://www.cityoflondon.police.uk</url>
      <address>37 Wood Street London EC2P 2NQ</address>
      <phone>020 7601 2455</phone>
      <logo>logo_city.gif</logo>
    </force>
...
<forces>


I did want to have indivdual <force>'s inside different <region>'s but gave up, I was just thinking about future use..  

Appreciate your interest! and thanks in advance for your help

Comment: ok, revisited this today, now have an XML file outpputting to screen in the correct format for the Accordion to do its stuff, but it isnt.. I get script time out warnings.

so the XML is working, the "html" format is correct, now jsut need to do some JS cleverness to somehow start the accodrdion after the xml has finihsed outputting... Hmmm

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote this tool last night that may help you. I know it's been many months since you had this problem but let me know what you think! It may be helpful now.

http://lytsp33d.com/xml-to-jquery-accordion/

Best regards,

Zach